# How to use std::unique_ptr on a struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, unique-ptr

The title says most of it, how do I do this? I've Googled around a bit and nothing has told me that it can't be done, but nothing has explained how to do it either.

Take this snippet of code here:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

int main(void)
{
    struct a_struct
    {
        char first;
        int second;
        float third;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<a_struct> my_ptr(new a_struct);

    my_ptr.first = "A";
    my_ptr.second = 2;
    my_ptr.third = 3.00;

    printf("%c\n%i\n%f\n",my_ptr.first, my_ptr.second, my_ptr.third);

    return(0);
}
```

As the people who can answer this already know, this doesn't work, it doesn't even compile.

My question is how do I make something like this work?

The compilation error (using g++-7) looks like

```
baduniqueptr6.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
baduniqueptr6.cpp:15:12: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct>’ has no member named ‘first’
     my_ptr.first = "A";
            ^~~~~
baduniqueptr6.cpp:16:12: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct>’ has no member named ‘second’
     my_ptr.second = 2;
            ^~~~~~
baduniqueptr6.cpp:17:12: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct>’ has no member named ‘third’
     my_ptr.third = 3.00;
            ^~~~~
baduniqueptr6.cpp:19:34: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct>’ has no member named ‘first’
     printf("%c\n%i\n%f\n",my_ptr.first, my_ptr.second, my_ptr.third);
                                  ^~~~~
baduniqueptr6.cpp:19:48: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct>’ has no member named ‘second’
     printf("%c\n%i\n%f\n",my_ptr.first, my_ptr.second, my_ptr.third);
                                                ^~~~~~
baduniqueptr6.cpp:19:63: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct>’ has no member named ‘third’
     printf("%c\n%i\n%f\n",my_ptr.first, my_ptr.second, my_ptr.third);
                                                               ^~~~~
```

Comment: Unrelated: [if `std::make_unique` is available to you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) you should make a habit of using it.  It eliminates a few error cases that the constructor and `new` do not protect you from.

Comment: The problem is `std::unique_ptr` is a `struct` by itself as well so using `.` on an instance of this type you trying to access member of `std::unique_ptr` not the struct it points to. For example you may call method `get()` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get `auto rawpointer = my_ptr.get();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [`->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) instead of `.`, `std::unique_ptr` is a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) which behaves similarly as raw pointers.

```
my_ptr->first = 'A';
my_ptr->second = 2;
my_ptr->third = 3.00;

printf("%c\n%i\n%f\n",my_ptr->first, my_ptr->second, my_ptr->third);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bSauD8cjPJ50Erf6)

Or you can use [`operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) to dereference on the pointer and then you can use `operator.`, this is also the same as raw pointers.

```
(*my_ptr).first = 'A';
(*my_ptr).second = 2;
(*my_ptr).third = 3.00;

printf("%c\n%i\n%f\n",(*my_ptr).first, (*my_ptr).second, (*my_ptr).third);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XUIL7lNas9uF9NB8)

PS: You should change `"A"` (which is a c-style string) to `'A'` (which is a `char`).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. g++ wasn't giving me much information about the problem.

Comment: @Mutaru Well, [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jCkFZFfzWBc0SJUo) gives the same message, but it gives one more hint, *did you mean to use '->' instead of '.'?*

Comment: Even better, initialize the smart pointer with `auto my_ptr = std::make_unique<a_struct>();`.